# Entity Framework TPH Inheritance Code First oftype

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, table-per-hierarchy

I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem properly.

I have a class `Appointment` and a class `AppointmentSeries` with inheritance from `Appointment`.

My database is set up code-first with TPH.

Now when I get the database, I want to get all rows with the type of `Appointment`, without the `AppointmentSeries`.

I tried using `OfType<Appointment>()` but this also gets the `AppointmentSeries`.

I read that I have to use abstract classes to get the correct behaviour, but I don't want to implement an abstract class so I have to implement the same properties in `Appointment` and `AppointmentSeries`. Or do I have to?

The other solution I found was to add `.where(a => !(a is AppointmentSeries))` to every query. But this is ugly and I get the entire database and then exclude some rows.

Is there a better way to get only the Appointments or structure my classes to I can use `OfType<Appointments>()`?

All the best

Canere

Comment: "want to get all ... Appointment, without the AppointmentSeries" means they were not good candidates for inheritance to begin with. Currently, your AppointmentSeries __is an__ Appointment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a try to the abstract class approach. You don't have to implement the same code in both derived classes. What you do is defining an abstract base class `BaseAppointment` containing all the code of your current `Appointment` class, and then defining `Appointment` like an empty class that just extends the base class without any code inside (perhaps just a constructor that calls the base abstract constructor):

```
class Appointment : BaseAppointment 
{
    public Appointment(...some params) : base(...some params) {}
}
```

`AppointmentSeries` also extends `BaseAppointment`, with no further changes (apart from the constructor calling base constructor as well, which it probably already does).

In your `DbContext` you define `DbSets` for `Appointment` and `AppointmentSeries`.

With this you will no longer get `AppointmentSeries` from the `Appointment` `DbSet`.

If you don't like this approach you could also consider changing from TPH to TPT (Table Per Type) or TPC (Table Per Concrete Class), and implementing both entities in separate tables.

Otherwise I guess you would have to go for the ugly and performance-impacting `.where(a => !(a is AppointmentSeries))` or something similar.

A trick that could work (but it is also ugly): if your `AppointmentSeries` has a non-nullable property which is not defined in the base `Appointment` class you can use it as a filter. This property will be always `null` in `Appointments`, but `not null` in `AppointmentSeries`. You can add a filter `.where(a => !(a.MyProperty is null))` to your queries. I don't really know if this has a better performance that the other  one.